# How to free Xlib cursor? XFreeCursor has no effect

Tags: c, free, xlib

Using [XCreateFontCursor()](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#XCreateFontCursor) and freeing it by [XFreeCursor()](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#XFreeCursor) has no effect. I keep getting memory use on exit using Valgrind.

Is there some way to fix this?

As far as I can understand there is no other resource references it after [XUndefineCursor](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#XUndefineCursor), nor after free on a unused cursor.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/cursorfont.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    Display *dpy;
    int scr;
    Window win = 0;
    Cursor curs = 0;

    if(!(dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL))) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Unable to open display.\n"
        );
        return 1;
    }

    scr = DefaultScreen(dpy);

    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        switch (argv[i][0]) {
        case 'w':
            win = XCreateSimpleWindow(
                dpy,
                XRootWindow(dpy, scr),
                200, 200,
                300, 200,
                2,
                XBlackPixel(dpy, scr),
                XWhitePixel(dpy, scr)
            );
            XMapWindow(dpy, win);
            XFlush(dpy);
            break;
        case 'c':
            fprintf(stdout, "Creating cursor.\n");
            curs = XCreateFontCursor(dpy, XC_diamond_cross);
            if (win)
                XDefineCursor(dpy, win, curs);
            break;
        case 'f':
            if (curs) {
                fprintf(stdout, "Freeing cursor.\n");
                if (win)
                    XUndefineCursor(dpy, win);
                XFreeCursor(dpy, curs);
            } else
                fprintf(stderr, "No cursor to free.\n");
            break;
        case 's':
            fprintf(stdout, "Sleep 1 second.\n");
            sleep(1);
            break;
        case 'u':
            fprintf(stdout, "Flushing display.\n");
            XFlush(dpy);
            break;
        }
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Close and free display.\n");
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c89 -o freecursor freecursor.c -lX11
```

Run:

```
# Test without cursor:
valgrind ./freecursor s u s
  in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
  total heap usage: 55 allocs, 55 frees, 47,438 bytes allocated

# Test with cursor:
valgrind ./freecursor c u s f u
  in use at exit: 21,680 bytes in 298 blocks
  total heap usage: 698 allocs, 400 frees, 99,849 bytes allocated

# Test with cursor and window:
valgrind ./freecursor w c u s f u s
  in use at exit: 21,680 bytes in 298 blocks
  total heap usage: 698 allocs, 400 frees, 99,849 bytes allocated

# Test with cursor and window + no free of cursor:
valgrind ./freecursor w s c u s
  in use at exit: 21,680 bytes in 298 blocks
  total heap usage: 698 allocs, 400 frees, 99,849 bytes allocated
```

---

Edit: Seems like something is done. Tried to create 15 different cursors and not freeing any of them and Valgrind reports same numbers of bytes *"in use at exit"* as if only one was created. Even so it is `XCreateFontCursor` that has this effect.

Comment: You don't allocate memory here - curs is automatic variable here (and is probably just uint32)

Comment: Yes, `curs` is an XID aka unsigned long, but doesn't it also a reference to a lower level allocated memory area? Like, simplified, having an index of an allocated array of objects. Upon `XFreeCursor` area where this ID is an index of should be freed - and if not then, then at least upon `XCloseDisplay()`. The XID returned is probably an index in a linked list of hidden memory management by Xlib.

Comment: not on the client side. It probably maps to some memory allocated on X server (indirectly, as XIDs are incremented by client and not returned as a result of X request)